# javascript split

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function frompost()
{
  var string=$('#indexsearch').val();
  var url=string.split('=');
  if(url==""){
  var url=string.split('video/');  
  }
  var finalurl='http://watchvideos.tv/watch/'+url[1];
  window.location = finalurl;
  //$('#srchFrm').attr('action',finalurl);
  //document.srchFrm.submit();
}
</script>
```

I have a problem with this script - it's Ok as long as indexsearch field contains `=` and fails when it's supposed to work as well - with `video/` in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function frompost()
{
  var str = $('#indexsearch').val(),
      url = str.split(/=|video\//),
      finalurl = 'http://watchvideos.tv/watch/'+url[1];
  window.location = finalurl;
}
```

Comment: `url[1]` is passed as `undefined` instead of the value after `video/`

Comment: What's the value of `$('#indexsearch').val()`?

Comment: Well `http://videobb.com/video/PFt6bfmNMSlW'.split(/=|video\//)` returns `["http://videobb.com/", "PFt6bfmNMSlW"]` here, so I'm not sure why url[1] shouldn't exist. Could *video/...* be in uppercase? Than use `.split(/=|video\//i)`